# Google nest connect to device

Tags: nest, google-smart-home, nest-device-access

I am looking to access the nest thermostat at my home.

I believe this can be accessed by an API, to start with I would just like to return some data about the device.

How would I go about doing this?  I did look into Google device access API.

This lead me to the device access console. This lets me create a sandbox account? However I would like to actually connect to my device?

How do I get this API for example working for my own device. What steps are needed and where do I get my device-id from?

```
GET /enterprises/project-id/devices/device-id
```

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox account does allow you to work with your own devices. But, the only way to communicate with Nest devices is through Device Access. You can find more information in this regard [here](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/codelabs/web-app).